# не могу подружить socket.io и redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, socket.io

Есть проблема.

Локально запущен сервер на socket.io, который раз в пять секунд отдаёт массив объектов.

Задача - поймать эти данные на клиентской стороне (тоже локально) и красиво распарсить в HTML (или хотя бы просто вывести на экран).

Для управления стейтом (оттуда будут браться данные для вывода на экран) используется redux. Я собрал редьюсер, добавил экшен, но всё работает как-то криво: то возвращается пустой объект, то два раза новый, то опять пустой.

Вот здесь лежит код: https://codesandbox.io/s/ilbg14

Как сделать так, чтобы содержимое ответа сервера записывалось в стор, а затем корректно выводилось на экран именно с частотой раз в пять секунд?

Нужен ли useEffect в данном случае? И какие должны быть зависимости, если да?

Спасибо.

Comment: Для начала уберите все `document.getElementById` - это ни разу не react. Вы таким образом вызываете мутацию DOM дерева, о которой react ничего не знает. Для отслеживания изменений в стейте нужен useEffect. Установку соединения по сокету и дальнейшую работу с ним вынесете в useEffect( , []). При получении данных вы должны только сохранять значения в стор.

Comment: Я сейчас закомментировал все document.getElementById и перенёс установку соединения с сокетом внутрь useEffect. Массив зависимостей пустой.

Если выводить myTickers в консоль, то каждые пять секунд я буду иметь там пустой массив.

Нужно, чтобы dispatch срабатывал каждый раз, когда сервер отдаёт новый массив. Как это сделать?

Comment: Повесить useEffect на ту переменную, которая принимает значения из стора

Comment: Ну перед useEffect у меня объявлены только const dispatch = useDispatch() и const myTickers = useSelector((state) => state). Они обе как-то слабо подходят. Я пробовал вынести из useEffect наружу переменную const socket = io('http://localhost:4000/') и добавить в массив зависимостей сам socket, но тогда сервер отдаёт массив, useEffect на основе этого события запускает dispatch и дает новую команду на запуск сервера и начало стриминга, и в консоли начинается катавасия.

Comment: Вот на эту переменную вам надо завязываться myTickers. Другое дело, что у вас возможно она не обновляется и из самого стора ничего не приходит

Comment: myTickers обновляется, когда dispatch отправляет в reducer новые данные, полученные от сервера (quotes). Моя задача - делать это раз в пять секунд, когда от сервера приходит новый массив, и затем выводить myTickers на экран (ну или в HTML).

Comment: То есть цепочка такая: сервер отдал quotes -> dispatch передал в редьюсер команду NEW_QUOTES и payload -> содержимое quotes записалось в myTickers -> myTickers отправился в HTML. И так раз в пять секунд.

Comment: `useEffect(() => { console.log(myTickers) }, [myTickers])` Если будет выводить данные, значит все ОК, не будет, не получаете обновление из редакса

Comment: Не выводит. :( Точнее, выводит, но сразу по несколько раз. 

Я загрузил весь код - и сервера, и клиента - сюда: https://codesandbox.io/s/rss3sk